# connect to a password protected shared folder over network using Delphi

Tags: delphi, networking, network-programming, directory, shared

I have a multi user Delphi program which needs a shared folder over network to store data. I want the program changes the files in that folder but not normal users (who can see this folder) or network viruses...

I want to protect this folder with a password (windows 7) but I need to write new files or edit existing files via my program and I don't know how to do this.

Briefly I need to connect and disconnect to a shared folder via code like this

```
ConnectToFolder(\\myServerMachine\mySharedfolder username:me password:myPassword);
disConnectToFolder(\\myServerMachine\mySharedfolder username:me password:myPassword);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this would probably do the trick

```
function ConnectShare(Drive, RemotePath, UserName, Password : String):Integer;
var
  NRW : TNetResource;
begin
  with NRW do
  begin
    dwType := RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    if Drive <> '' then
      lpLocalName := PChar(Drive)
    else
      lpLocalName := nil;
    lpRemoteName := PChar(RemotePath);
    lpProvider := '';
  end;
  Result := WNetAddConnection2(NRW, PChar(Password), PChar(UserName), 0);
end;

function DisconnectShare(Drive : String):Integer;
begin
  Result := WNetCancelConnection2(PChar(Drive), 0, false);
end;
```

Comment: it looks great but couldn't exactly solve it. Could you give an example, forexample the name of the machine is MyComputer in my system and the folder is C:\Mysharedfolder in that machine

Comment: If C:\MySharedFolder on the remote machine has share name MySharedFolder , I think RemoteShare would be '\\MyComputer\MySharedFolder'

Comment: and drive is just C or like C:\

Comment: By the way when I try using this function it retuns 1200 whether username or password is correct or not...

Comment: THE ANSWER: interesting but as it is clearly seen in the code the answer is let drive name '' (empty) at least in my case

Comment: however There is very important problem. AVG considers my application as if it is virus :(

Comment: What parameters are you passing in? 1200 is "The Specified Device Name Is Invalid"

Comment: as I said the main problem is now - which is probably not solvable- is TNetResource is considered as virus for AVG and probably for other antivirus programs...